# How to check in # in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Sometimes because of cache I add # in my url, like this:

```
http://www.example.com/#lang=3201954253
```

What I need is to check if there is #lang in url and remove it if present.

Answer (score 2):

you can clear the hash.

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

or you can even use history api  [History Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). `history.pushState` and `replaceState`

history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.

```
window.history.replaceState( {} , 'foo', '/foo' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // code
} else {
  // code
}
```

or you may try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (location.href.indexOf("#") != -1) {
        //code
    }
</script>
```

If you want to remove it then you may try this:

```
window.location.hash = ''
```

**On a side note:**

You may try

```
window.location.href.split('#')[0]
```

to remove anything after `#` without refreshing your page.

Comment: @Schneider window.location.hash = '' will do that for you

Comment: @Schneider:- You may also try `window.location.href.split('#')[0]` to remove the anything after # without refreshing your page

Comment: @Schneider:- You may also use this fucntion: `function removeHash() { 
    window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    btn.disabled = !(location.hash || location.href.slice(-1) == "#");     
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var tel = window.location.href;

if(tel.indexOf("#") > -1){
    alert("found");
} else {
    alert('not found')   
}
```

Comment: Example is just example i dont know the url :(( Also i want to remove it :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.hash.indexOf("lang")) {
  window.location.hash = "";
}
```